FlyingSphinx::Error: BLOCKED: Single-index processing is not permitted for your plan level
I Have error,
FlyingSphinx::Error: BLOCKED: Single-index processing is not permitted for your plan level,
Stack:
heroku 22
"Flying Sphinx": Wooden
Rails 6
Sphinx
Flying Sphinx
Delayed Job ( Delta job)

Error: BLOCKED: Single-index processing is not permitted for your plan level
Because of the extra load that delta processing involves, it's not an option on the lowest (Wooden) plan - you will need to upgrade to Ceramic to use delta indexing. This is noted in the plan tiers here:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/flying_sphinx
But, it may be worth considering real-time indices instead of SQL-backed indices, as this allows immediate updates to records, no deltas required, and so then you can remain on the Wooden plan.
https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v5/real_time
Kind regards,
credit : Pat Allan
